# how to create a versioned DLL , and compile using text or xml as resource?

Tags: c++, dll, compilation, versioning

I'm creating a DLL and want it to be compiled with a text file or xml , containing it's version. How can I do it? 
I want during the compilation->access a certain "information file" and the DLL will use it's "version" and "company name" for example...and use it as the properties of the DLL.

I don't even know where and how to start... any help would be appreciated!

thank you!:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily achieve this with `verpatch` which is available here:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37133/Simple-Version-Resource-Tool-for-Windows

However, you need to pass your version information on command-line, so need to setup your tool chain to generate it from your version text file. We do this with CMake.